# Solving an optimization problem with inequality constraints with absolute values

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\xi=(\xi_{1},\ldots,\xi_{N})\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $\varepsilon >0$, I need to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
{\displaystyle \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{N}} } & {\displaystyle \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\xi_{i}-x_{i}) }  \\
\text{subject to} & {\displaystyle  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left|x_{i}\right| \leq \varepsilon }
\end{array}
$$

**Remark:** In this [link](http://mat.gsia.cmu.edu/classes/QUANT/NOTES/chap4/node6.html)  they deal with optimization problems with inequality constraints, my problem is that in my case the constraints involved absolute values and I do not see how this information can help.

Comment: @Magnussen is correct below---but that suggests to me that perhaps you didn't write down the problem correctly, since the $\xi$ values are irrelevant. Are you sure about this formulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\xi$ is constant, the problem is equivalent to $$\min \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i, \text{ s.t. } \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|\leq \epsilon.$$ Note that if we change $x_i$ by $-x_i,$ te constraint is not affected. Hence we can restrict our attention to the case when $x_i\leq 0.$ But then we have

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N -x_i=\frac{1}N \sum_{i=1}^N |x_i|\leq \epsilon,$$ from which we find

$$\frac 1 N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i\geq -\epsilon.$$ It is now easy to see that $\bar{x}=-\epsilon e$ is a solution $(e=(1,\ldots,1)^T)$.